# input oninvalid custom message still maintains invalid after selecting the box

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

Working on a getting an input (checkbox) to show a custom message when it is invalid (not checked), but after that messages is shown if the user checks the box the message is still shown and considered invalid. I think it has to do with the oninvalid but not sure.

**code for input**

`<input style="width:15px; height:15px; cursor: pointer;" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" onclick="setCustomValidity('')" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please review the legal agreement and check this box to proceed')" required>`

**picture of what I'm getting after first getting the error message, then checking the box**

[image: error image]
`

Comment: where is `setCustomValidity` code?

Comment: @GibralterTop the `setCustomValidity` method just assigns the message for invalid, [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/setCustomValidity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this worked for me

```
            <input style="width:15px; height:15px; cursor: pointer;" name="legal"
        class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" required id="legal"
        onchange="this.setCustomValidity(validity.valueMissing ? 'Please review the legal agreement and check this box to proceed' : '');">
```

and on the controller

```
    document.getElementById("legal").setCustomValidity("Please review the legal agreement and check this box to proceed");
```